# Jquery multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm using jQuery to validate and then AJAX to submit multiple forms on a single page. The user will only complete one form per visit. Currently jQuery is only able to target and validate the first form and I'm unsure how to adapt it to handle the presence of the other forms - the script was taken from a one-form environment where it worked well.  I've seen various posts about being able to do this, but I couldn't figure out how to apply them to my situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });    

     $('a').click(function(e) {
         $('#product').val($(this).attr('id'));     
         $('#sub').val('I am interested in ' + this.id);    
     });        

     $("#send").on("click", function(){
        var emailval  = $("#email").val();
        var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
        var nameval    = $("#name").val();
        var namelen    = nameval.length;

        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(msglen < 4) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(msglen >= 4){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(namelen < 1) {
            $("#name").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(namelen >= 1){
            $("#name").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4 && namelen >= 1) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<span class=sending>sending...</span>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'rfq.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<span class=success>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 5000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: # is ID and all IDs have to be unique. Change the #send to .send and add a class="send" to the button. Then change the other # to $(this).closest('form').find(....); Perhaps using name instead of ID

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks.  This got me pointed in the right direction w/ validation.  I may edit the question depending on whether the form submit works upon testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas of how you can do it. I did not finish it because I do not have time to wire up a form dumper to test it all nor to run fancybox and create all the html that goes with it.

It is a generic handler that should handle multiple forms with class "contact" which all have a name, email and msg field

Some of the selectors you will have to modify, for example I do not know if you want a send span for each form so I assumed you did and that it is a sibling of form

```
    $(".contact").submit(function() { 
        var form = $(this);
        var name  = form.find("input[name='fullname']");
        var email = form.find("input[name='email']");
        var msg   = form.find("input[name='msg']")

        var emailval  = email.val();
        var msgval    = msg.val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);
        var nameval    = name.val();
        var namelen    = nameval.length;

        name.toggleClass("error",namelen < 1) 
        email.toggleClass("error",!mailvalid);
        msg.toggleClass("error",msglen< 4) 

        if (name.hasClass("error") || email.hasClass("error") || msg.hasClasss("error")) return false;

        form.sibling(".send").replaceWith("<span class=sending>sending...</span>");

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'rfq.php',
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            if(data == "true") {
              $(form).fadeOut("fast", function(){
                $(this).before("<span class=success>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");
                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 5000);
              });
            } // if
          } // success
        }); // ajax
        return false; // cancel the submit
      });
```